# Not able to process the code that contains df.collect() method in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to get the 'Row_id' values where there is 'Match=False' in my data frame using pyspark. The following code I have used works pretty fine. but the same code fails to execute if the count of the rows of the data frame is more than 1000. will anybody please guide me achieve the same result for big size files? The format of the file can be anything like csv,json,parquet.

```
listt=[]
for x in range(len(dat.collect())):
    for y in range(len(dat.collect()[x])):
        if dat.collect()[x][y]==False:
            listt=listt+[dat.collect()[x][0]]
```

My data frame looks like below.

```
Row_id    Name   Months       Match
   1    elissa       20          TRUE
   2    carlson      30          FALSE
   3    jose         13          FALSE
   4    sara         2           FALSE
   5    meera        5           FALSE
   6    kaarlos      8           FALSE
   7    chris        1           TRUE
   8    bruse        9           TRUE
   9    john         24          TRUE
  10    deppy        35          TRUE
```

Comment: Store `data.collect()` to a variable. Use that variable in the `for` and `if`. Multiple collects of the same data on every iteration will fail once file sizes exceed a certain amount.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can select the data by filtering the dataframe and select only the id column, collect.

```
id_list = [x[0] for x in df.filter('Match = False').select('Row_id').collect()]
id_list

[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```